# Unable to get managed connection ERROR in Wildfly and MS SQL Server

Tags: database-connection, connection-pooling, sql-server-2017, jtds, wildfly-9

We have installed SQL Server 2017 and Java 1.8.0_261-b12 in our production environment. We are using Wildfly 9.01 and JTDS driver to access the database.

We have defined datasource/database connection pool configuration in `standalone.xml` like this:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/dmsdb" pool-name="dmsdb" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" statistics-enabled="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://0.0.2.5:1482;DatabaseName=dmsdb;tds=8.0;lastupdatecount=true</connection-url>
    <connection-property name="sendStringParametersAsUnicode">true</connection-property>
    <driver>jtds</driver>
    <new-connection-sql>SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sysusers WHERE 1 = -1</new-connection-sql>
    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
    <pool>
    <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
    <max-pool-size>600</max-pool-size>
    <flush-strategy>IdleConnections</flush-strategy>
    </pool>
    <security>
    <user-name>dmsdb</user-name>
    <password>${VAULT::ds_dmsdb::password::1}</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
    <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sysusers WHERE 1 = -1</check-valid-connection-sql>
    <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
    </validation>
    <timeout>
    <idle-timeout-minutes>1</idle-timeout-minutes>
    </timeout>
    <statement>
    <track-statements>false</track-statements>
    <prepared-statement-cache-size>0</prepared-statement-cache-size>
    </statement>
</datasource>
```

Suddenly we got this error in our application log:

```
2023-01-04 11:26:17,880 ERROR [com.test.base.persistence.dao.BaseDAO] (pool-89-thread-10511) SQLException in BaseDAO.getDBConnection():javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/dmsdb: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/dmsdb
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:146)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:67)
    at com.test.base.persistence.dao.BaseDAO.getDBConnection(BaseDAO.java:109)
    at com.test.base.persistence.dao.BaseDAO.getCallableStatement(BaseDAO.java:270)
    at com.test.adoddle.watch.persistence.AdoddleObjectWatcherDAO.isResourceBeingWatched(AdoddleObjectWatcherDAO.java:121)
    at com.test.adoddle.watch.bizlogic.AdoddleObjectWatcherEJB.isResourceBeingWatched(AdoddleObjectWatcherEJB.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor507.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:73)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInNoTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:263)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.supports(CMTTxInterceptor.java:374)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:243)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.processInvocation(EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbSuspendInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbSuspendInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:634)
    at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:195)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.LocalEjbReceiver.processInvocation(LocalEjbReceiver.java:261)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:184)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBObjectInterceptor.handleInvocation(EJBObjectInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:186)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBHomeInterceptor.handleInvocation(EJBHomeInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:186)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionInterceptor.handleInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:42)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:186)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:125)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:186)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.sendRequestWithPossibleRetries(EJBInvocationHandler.java:255)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:200)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:183)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:146)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy101.isResourceBeingWatched(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.adoddle.watch.bd.AdoddleObjectWatcherBD.isResourceBeingWatched(AdoddleObjectWatcherBD.java:60)
    at com.test.common.notification.listener.WatchableObjectActivityListener.onEvent(WatchableObjectActivityListener.java:41)
    at com.test.common.eventbus.EventBroadcaster.run(EventBroadcaster.java:61)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/dmsdb
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:646)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:430)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:737)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:138)
    ... 88 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:336)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:343)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:278)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:1224)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:484)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:622)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:594)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:579)
    ... 91 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:436)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:312)
    ... 98 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:476)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:218)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:394)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.createSocketForJDBC3(SharedSocket.java:288)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.<init>(SharedSocket.java:251)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:331)
    ... 100 more
```

When we checked connections in DB on that time we got the 570 sessions status were sleeping and other sessions(30) were running.

Refer to this screenshot:

[image]

Any suggestions or configuration to avoid above issue?

Comment: you're using a really old driver against a modern sql server. From what i remember, it doesn't support latest TDS needed to handle prelogin that is required. It might work if you set encrypt=false in connection string, as well as getting the patch for ssl from the jtds homepage. *BUT*, and here's the but, you shouldn't be using jtds at all, unless you want to work with really old servers. the MS driver is fine for most things nowadays, so get it instead